# ¿Como pasar datos en DataGridView a Otro DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo dos `DataGridView` de esta manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es que los `CheckBox` que esten seleccionados del primer `DatagridView` al pulsar el `Button` "agregar" se pasen al segundo `DataGridView`.NOTA: El `total` del segundo `DataGridView` lo calculare a partir de la columna `cantidad` y `precio` (que esta oculta).
De verdad ya intente de algunas formas con el poco conocimiento que tengo, pero creo que estoy muy alejado de conseguirlo, así que espero que me puedan ayudar gracias.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvInsumo.Rows)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[1].Value))
                    {
                        foreach (DataGridViewRow row2 in dgvInsumosAgregados.Rows)
                        {
                            dgvInsumosAgregados[0, row2.Index].Value = dgvInsumo[0, row.Index].Value;
                            dgvInsumosAgregados[1, row2.Index].Value = dgvInsumo[2, row.Index].Value;
                            dgvInsumosAgregados[2, row2.Index].Value = dgvInsumo[3, row.Index].Value;
                            dgvInsumosAgregados[3, row2.Index].Value = dgvInsumo[4, row.Index].Value;                            
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Sistema Restaurante", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
```

Esta fue de la ultima manera que intente, lo mas seguro es que este muy mal.
Gracias ya me muestra algo por lo menos pero lo hace de esta manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Probablemente porque no están las columnas de ambos `DataGridView` en el mismo orden o con el mismo nombre.

Comment: Yo te recomendaria que guardes los resultados de la interacción del usuario en la base de datos, y ya una vez allí, obtienes los datos desde el segundo grid con los datos del resultado

Comment: Deberías añadir lo que has intentado, aunque no sea correcto. [es.so] no es un servicio de código gratuito. Pásate por [ask] para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta

Comment: Me parece que estas muy cerca. Sería importante que dijeras cual es el problema con tu código. No hace lo que debe? Te lanza alguna excepción?

Comment: no, no me lanza ninguna excepción simplemente no me manda pasa los valores al otro DGV

Comment: Bien,el primer problema que tienes es que estas intentando un `foreach` en las filas de `dgvInsumosAgregados`...cuando en realidad no tiene ninguna. Lo que debes hacer es crear una nueva `DataGridViewRow`, meterle los datos de la que estas copiando y añadirla a `dgvInsumosAgregados`

Comment: Le estas recomendando que guarde las selecciones del usuario (que son volátiles y no se usan mas que en ese momento) en la base de datos, para que después las recupere? me parece una muy mala idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas muy cerca de la solución. Lo que debes hacer es **añadir** un nuevo `DataGridViewRow` a tu segundo `DataGridView`:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvInsumo.Rows)
{
     try
     {
          if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[1].Value))
          {
               dgvInsumosAgregados.Rows.Add(row.Cells[0].Value,
                                            row.Cells[2].Value, 
                                            row.Cells[3].Value, 
                                            row.Cells[4].Value)                           
          }

     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Sistema Restaurante", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
     }
}
```

Aqui [DataGridView.Rows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows(v=vs.110).aspx) tienes un ejemplo de como añadir e insertar nuevas filas a un `DataGridView`

Comment: ya me muestra pero lo hace como lo puse en imagen de arriba, veré si puedo hacer algo gracias por responder

Comment: @U.C, si has copiado el código tal y como yo te lo he puesto, no debería verse como pones en tu imagen. Edita tu pregunta y copia exactamente el código que tienes ahora

Comment: si gracias me base en tu código y ya pude solucionarlo gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Ya pude, solo le puse el numero de `celda` del segundo `DataGridView` asi:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvInsumo.Rows)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[1].Value))
                    {                       

                        DataGridViewRow fila = new DataGridViewRow();
                        fila.CreateCells(dgvInsumosAgregados);
                        fila.Cells[0].Value = row.Cells[0].Value;
                        fila.Cells[1].Value = row.Cells[2].Value;
                        fila.Cells[2].Value = row.Cells[4].Value;
                        fila.Cells[4].Value = row.Cells[3].Value;
                        dgvInsumosAgregados.Rows.Add(fila);
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Sistema Restaurante", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
```

Gracias a todos por responder fueron de mucha ayuda.